# d3js - how to rotate a map using d3js

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to display Australia using d3. I could centre my map but couldn't rotate it property so it'd properly displayed..

Here is the relevant code,

```
var projection = d3.geo.albers().scale(1).translate([0,0]);
var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);
var bounds = path.bounds(topojson.feature(dataSet, dataSet.objects.abs_aus_ced_2007));  
var scale = 0.95 /Math.max((bounds[1][0] - bounds[0][0])/width, (bounds[1][1] - bounds[0][1])/height);
var translate = [(width - scale * (bounds[1][0] + bounds[0][0])) / 2, (height - scale * (bounds[1][1] + bounds[0][1])) / 2];

projection.scale(scale).translate(translate);

path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);
```

Map is rotated about 80degrees clockwise.. I couldn't work out how to correct the rotation to display the map properly.

Any pointer would be awesome!!

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure this is long resolved, but for posterity:

Just add `var rotate = [x,y,z]` with x,y,z as the number of degrees you want to rotate in each of the three axes (see 3-axis rotation link below).  Sounds like your case might be fixed by rotation in z by -45 degrees, giving `var rotate = [0,0,-45]` or `var rotate = [0,0,135]`.

Then below:

```
projection.scale(scale).translate(translate).rotate(rotate);
```

Alternatively, put your map in a `g` element and specify the rotation using the html transform property `transform=rotate(-45)` on the `g` element:

```
var trans_x = (width - scale * (bounds[1][0] + bounds[0][0])) / 2 
var trans_y = (height - scale * (bounds[1][1] + bounds[0][1])) / 2
var rotation = 135
var svg = d3.select('#your_viz_container')
          .append('g')
          .transform('translate('+trans_x+','+trans_y+') rotate('+rotation+')')
```

Then append your path to the rotated `g`.

d3 3-axis rotation:
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4282586

Bostock's "Let's make a map":
http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/

Answer (score 2):

```
center = function( latitude, longitude ){
  var center = [ parseInt(longitude) * -1, parseInt(latitude) * -1 ];
  d3GlobeProj.rotate(center);
  d3Globe.refresh();
}
```

Comment: Code only answers can generally be improved by adding explanation to them.

Comment: This helped me solve and issue and I was overthinking the answer to my problem.  Sometimes the simple answers are best.   I do agree though that more than just code helps - however, in this instance it was perfect for me.

Answer (score 0):

Albers equal area projection is used in d3.geo.conicEqualArea() and has a .center() method that allows you to set the center of the projection. You can see it in action dynamically here:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3788999

d3.geo.albers also has a .center() method, so if you set your center to

```
var projection = d3.geo.albers().scale(1).translate([0,0]).center([133.5, 24.25])
```

You should be fine.

Comment: Thanks Elijah, tried that still no luck..wish I could upload an image so you could take a look. let me have a go any way..lets say if '-' is what I needed to show, the image is comping up as '\' so I reckon..I need to rotate the image such that it comes up as '-'. Hope it makes sense. Also, I've used centroid method to find out the centre automatically as well..I've pretty much got the same centre..